# Pdf libraries that allow rendering and editing in android

Tags: android, pdf

I am working on an android application which requires rendering and editing a PDF file. I have tried using PDFtron, but all the editing functionalities are inbuilt. I need a library that would allow me to add my own editing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can make pdftron work.  You just can't use their built in view.  Instead, use its functionality to render a page into a bitmap, and draw the bitmap onto your own view.  Then you can add the editing functionality and draw it back onto the pdf using pdftron.  Its a moderate amount of work though, especially if you want to do scrolling, zooming, and other things their view does built in.

Of course its not going to be too much different using any other library, and pdftron works on most pdfs so its a pretty good start if you can afford their freaking insane license fees.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help. Can you recommend another library with good documentation

Comment: I've used qoppa, it has decent but not great documentation, good response on bug fixes, and much more reasonable licensing fees.  There's also raede pdf, but I never investigated too deeply-  their example app crashed too much for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mupdf for your purpose ....

https://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/list

Comment: Does mupdf allow editing pdf files

Comment: check the documentation i had created the app

Comment: Did your app support editing.